# Remove navigation bar back button title without breaking transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In iOS 7 Apple introduced new transition when you push view controller on top of another view controller. The transition comes with nice animation and back gesture. The back button displays the title from previous view controller which is good for accessibility:

[image: Navigation Bar in Apple Health]

1. You know where you are by looking on a title. You know that title is not intractable because it has different to tint color, usually, black.
2. You know where you come from with the back button label.

Unfortunately, our design require to remove navigation bar label because sometimes it is too long and it move navigation bar title to the right a little.

Here is how our design should look and work during the transition:
[image: SoundCloud app]

We removed the title from the first view controller in `viewDidLoad` of the first view controller (the one which is behind):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Now our transition has status bar background color problem:
[image: Our app transition]

Status bar change background color to grey during transition. Both view controllers have white status bar background.

Pushing second view controller:

```
SecondVC *svc = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController svc animated:YES];`
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove this line from our code:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:Colour_White];
```

Answer (score 0):

In first ViewController -

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *btn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=btn;

}
```